# How do I display a different website logo to mobile users in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, e-commerce

I'm working on E-Commerce theme and I've been trying to make the site display a different logo if the device is a mobile, is this possible?

**NOTE:** I'm using a WordPress theme called `storefront`.

Comment: Do you use `<img>` tag or `<div>` and in css `background`? Without even a snippet of code, I can not answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style>  
  .sitelogo .mobilelogo {
    display: none;
  }

  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .sitelogo .mobilelogo {
      display: block;
    }
    .sitelogo .desktoplogo {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="sitelogo">
  <img src="/images/logo_desktop.png" class="desktoplogo" />
  <img src="/images/logo_mobile.png" class="mobilelogo" />
</div>
```

And also try following code, Check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) for better reference

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Include/display resources targeted to phones/tablets here */
} else {
    /* Include/display resources targeted to laptops/desktops here */
}
```